# Movie about a haunted house involves killing in dreams / Swimming pool

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember it's an Australian movie with a plot something like this:
A guy has to take care of a large, empty house with a swimming pool because the owners take a vacation. The next day there is a girl in the pool and she says that she has the keys and she is some relative. Guy falls in love with her, etc. The plot always involves the guy getting up and unable to determine whether it was a dream or not. In the end he gets locked into the house and his girlfriend is unable to open the doors or windows. At last he wakes up in the hospital, but realizes that he is dead and the evil (ghost girl) is the nurse.

Comment: There are interesting similarities with the 1986 movie *House*.  A guy is living in a large house with a swimming pool, and weird things happen and it isn't always clear if they are real.  There's also an attractive woman who swims in the pool and the guy likes her...  The ending is totally different though.  I like and recommend the movie *House*; it's really original.

Comment: @steveha Thanks I will watch it too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it. It's *[Crush](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1170350/?ref_=sr_6)*.

> An American student studying in Australia mistakenly gets involved with a mysterious and unhinged girl while house-sitting for a rich family on vacation.